# JMeter idle Threads/Users

Tags: jmeter

I have a practical Challenge:

I need to validate that a server-timeout appears after 5 seconds (as in a 400/500 response-code) under a JMeter loadtest with 100 threads running constantly and requesting a url simulataniously.

Is it possible to configure JMeter to idle/delay/keep running each thread/user for a custom period of time?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question right but maybe jmeter's [timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) is something your are looking for?

Comment: Hi, does timers (from the link you posted: "If you want to have each thread pause for the same amount of time between requests, use this timer) hold the thread in memory for as long as it is set to?

Comment: I just need to idle the requests per sample for i.e. 5 secounds, as in keep the thread for 5 Seconds before releasing it. This way of course the response time will be at leats 5 secounds.

Comment: Hm, you can possibly try to look into [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) but not sure that's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is Constant Timer . Read the below link to know more about it.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer

This will help you pause the threads for a constant amount of time before releasing it to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which actually lets you run as much as you define it :

> Desired runtime in seconds